# How to move through each line in getline()

Tags: c++, c++11

Whenever I run my code, I get the first line pulled out of the file, but only the first. Is there something I am missing? I ran into the issue when I implemented stringstream to try and more easily read in the lines of hex from the file and more quickly convert between a string to a hex value. It read in each line accordingly before, but now it is not. Am I missing something in the understanding of how getline() works?

ss is stringstream, fileIn is the file, hexInput is a string, memory[] is an array of short int, instruction is a short int, opCounter is an int...

```
string hexInput;
stringstream ss;
short int instruction;
ifstream fileIn ("proj1.txt");

if (fileIn.is_open())
{
    while ( getline(fileIn, hexInput) ) 
    {
        ss << hex << hexInput;
        ss >> instruction;

        memory[opCounter] = instruction;

        cout << hex << memory[opCounter] << '\t';
        cout << opCounter << '\n';

        ss.str("");
        opCounter++;
    }
    fileIn.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

Above is the entire function (which was working before using stringstream) and below are the contents of the file.

```
4000
0033
0132
2033
4321
2137
D036
A00F
B003
C00C
3217
6217
E044
FFFF
6016
1013
FFFF
0
0
0
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

There are 26 lines and the last opCounter output says "19" in hex which makes me assume the file is being read line-by-line, but the stringstream never updated. This is my first C++ program and am new to a few of these features I am trying to implement.
Thanks for any help...

Comment: How do you know you're only reading the first line?

Comment: I assume such because the first cout displays what is the first line of the file and the second shows proper increment of the opCounter; I have also tried simply outputting instruction through each pass, but the results are the exact same.

Comment: Can you show us more code that deals with this specific problem? That is, show us what's going on before the `getline` runs. Also, please show us the contents of the file.

Comment: getline does not return status so your while is not correct.

Comment: @stark His `while` loop is correct as [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) returns the stream which checks its stream state which will indicate any problems during extraction.

Comment: The first thing to do, it seems to me, is to print `hexInput` after you've read it: `cout << hexInput;` plus a newline if `getline()` removes it.  That'll tell you what's going on with `getline()`; you can then start worrying about what happens with `ss`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I just inserted a cout with hexInput and it is in fact going through each line of the file...I have tried ss.str(""); as found from other questions to try and clear ss, but that does not seem to alleviate the problem.

Comment: Try doing `ss.clear()` after `s >> instruction`.

Comment: @stark `getline` returns `iostream&`, which has an overload for `operator bool()`, so the while is indeed correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stringstream is created correctly from the first line. After outputting the number into `instruction` it will be `eof` though (you can check this with `ss.eof()`) because there is no data after the first number inside the stringstream.

replace `ss.str("");` (which you don't need) by `ss.clear();` which will reset the `eof` flag. Inputting the new line and reading from the stream will then work as expected.

Of course there is absolutely no need for a stringstream in the first place.

```
while ( fileIn.good() ) {
    fileIn >> hex >> instruction;
    [...]
}
```

works fine. It will read short ints in hexadecimal representation until one line cannot be interpreted as such. (Which incidentally is line 7 because D036 is too large to fit inside a short int - admittedly that is different from your current behaviour, but did you really want a silent failure? very useful at this point are again `fileIn.eof()` to check whether the read failed due to the stream being at the end of the file and `fileIn.clear()` to reset other fail-bits)

As requested:
The loop is commonly abbreviated as

```
while ( fileIn >> hex >> instruction ) {
    [...]
}
```

but note, that if you want to check why the read failed, and continue if it was not an `eof`, the aforementioned loop is more suited to the task.

Comment: +1. Also, you might want to change that to `while (fileIn >> hex >> instruction)`

Comment: @0x499602D2  That depends. He might want to check whether the read failed due to the `eof` flag or because the number did not fit inside the short int (in which case he could eg continue with the next line)

Comment: @example: Novices almost never want to do that, and everyone else usually does if after the while loop.  But at least mention it in the post.  Also `ss.str("")` resets the content of the stream in conforming implementatoins.

Comment: @MooingDuck i have removed the "not doing anything in most implementations" part about the `.str("")` because it is not relevant. What most implementations (and his aswell as it seems) will do is to set the read and write pointers to the same position (as the passed string is empty) - but as it is already `eof` this is already the case. The standard does not require the underlying buffer to be resetted - and at least in gcc and afaik vc it will be untouched. (this is why the sourcode in the question read out 0x4000 19 times)

Comment: @example: (1) The OP never said the sourcecode read out `0x4000` 19 times, but that's a possible result because the stream was in a bad state.  (2) The standard DOES require the underlying buffer to be reset with `.str`, and in this case it prevents the stringstream from growing large.  You were thinking of `.setbuf` or something

Comment: Just wanted to give a quick thanks for the help and tips! My interpreter is now quickly progressing and making solid headway. Thanks again!